# Canbus over canberry with raspberry pi two messages together at the same time

Tags: raspberry-pi, c, can

Im using a canberry with raspberry pi. Is there any way possible to send two messages at the same time with same id and be received by the other raspberry without any particular chance of getting a middle man attack ? I mean if someone is using the same id would it possible to prevent this in your opinion ? I made a research and I cannot find anything particular to this.

Comment: CAN bus has no "security", it was never intended for such applications. If someone has acccess to your CAN bus that shouldn't have it, then it's either because they are a burglar or because some IdiOticThing (IOT) has connected the bus to a live internet connection through firmware updates etc. In case of burglars, take the usual counter-measures such as locks. In case of IdioticThings, remove them from the CAN bus.

Answer (score 0):

Not only can an attacker send a frame with the same ID as you, it can also make different receivers see the same frame as having different data, according to Ken Tindell who has developed the [Janus Frame Attack](https://kentindell.github.io/2020/01/20/new-can-hacks/). This depends on the receivers having different sampling points, which is against the CAN guidelines but could occur if the nodes are from different manufacturers.

Comment: is there a way to allow messages >7 on canbus? According to STN1100 you can use ATAL for this particular reason but is there something already implemented for CAN ?

Comment: Yes with [CAN FD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_FD), but this seems to be a seperate topic from your original question. Please note that this is not a discussion board but a Q& A site where each question and answer gets votes, so mixing up topics is discouraged.

Comment: These kind of "hacks" are clever but at the same time rather silly. It isn't some TCP/IP thing... once you are live on a CAN bus, you can do pretty much whatever you want. My favourite "hack" being to cut the wires and replace a node with your own...